# release memory when reading a h5 file

Tags: python, memory-management, python-xarray, h5py

I have a bunch of h5 files of around 200 GB each. The structure of those files is the following:

```
file1.h5
├image  [float64: 3341 × 126 × 256 × 256]
├pulse  [uint64: 126]
└train  [uint64: 3341]
```

I wrote a the following code to read those files:

```
def read_h5(file_name, pulse_avg=True, train_idx=0, pulse_idx=0):
    """
    Read image data from a h5 file to a xarray
    """
    hf = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
    
    if not pulse_avg:
        coords = {'train': np.array(hf.get(f'train')),
                  'pulse': np.array(hf.get(f'pulse')),}
        dims = ['train','pulse','slow_scan','fast_scan']
        xarr = xr.DataArray(np.array(hf.get(f'image')),
                                     dims=dims, coords=coords)
        del hf
        return xarr.isel(train=train_idx).isel(pulse=pulse_idx)
    
    else:
        coords = {'train': np.array(hf.get(f'train'))}
        dims = ['train','slow_scan','fast_scan']
        xarr = xr.DataArray(np.array(hf.get(f'image')),
                            dims=dims, coords=coords)
        del hf
        return xarr
```

Note that I'm explicitly deleting the hf object used for reading the file.

When reading a whole file, the memory usage is as expected because the object is huge:

```
dummy = images_from_disk('file1.h5', pulse_avg=False,train_idx=slice(None),
                         pulse_idx=slice(None))
dummy.nbytes * (2 ** -30)
205.2626953125
```

Memory used before reading:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           754G         41G        697G         18M         15G        710G
Swap:          4.0G        132M        3.9G
```

Memory used after reading:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           754G        247G        491G         18M         15G        504G
Swap:          4.0G        132M        3.9G
```

But if I read the same file but keep a smaller version of it (only two pulses instead of 126), the size of the object is obviously smaller but memory is not released:

```
dummy_reduced = images_from_disk('file1.h5', pulse_avg=False,train_idx=slice(None),
                                  pulse_idx=slice(None,2))
dummy_reduced.nbytes * (2 ** -30)
3.2626953125
```

Memory used before reading:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           754G         41G        697G         18M         15G        710G
Swap:          4.0G        132M        3.9G
```

Memory used after reading:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           754G        247G        491G         18M         15G        504G
Swap:          4.0G        132M        3.9G
```

How can I release memory to concatenate more than 3 of those h5 files?
The code that will do the job will be something similar to this:

```
test = xr.concat([images_from_disk(file, pulse_avg=False,
                                   train_idx=slice(None,10),
                                   pulse_idx=slice(None,2)) for file in my_files],
                pd.Index([int(file.stem[-2:]) for file in my_files], name='module'))
```

Comment: `hf` is an opened file.  You close it, not `del`.  It doesn't take up much memory.  THe memory use comes from creating numpy arrays from the datasets: `np.array(hf.get(f'train')`.  From the `h5py` docs, the preferred way of loading an array is `arr = hf['train'[[:]`.  With that you can load portions as well, `arr = hf['train'][:n]`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj! It solved my problem :D